# SharepontOnline access with azure ad token

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to access sharepoint online from desktop app with azure ad token, but as a currently logged user?
I already registered client app in the azure ad and i'm able to connect to share point when the api permissions are set to "Application permissions", but when i set the permissions to "Delegated permissions" I can't access sharepoint site.
What i need is a way to create sp ClientContext based on the token i get from the azure. I know it's possible to try with SharePointOnlineCredentials, but i don't want to mess with users credentials.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Access Token for Azure, pls use the below article.

[active-directory-dotnet-native-headless](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless)

**Below are the steps you have to follow:**

1. Followed the steps mentioned in the article
2. Added Office 365 Sharepoint Online API access permissions for the App.
3. Selected necessary permissions for the App.

Comment: thanks for replay. I'm able to get a token from azure, but the thing is that i can only connect to sp when sharepointonline permissions are set to "Application permissions", not "Delegated permissions"

Comment: Unauthorized. I managed to fix the problem by using OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetAzureADAccessTokenAuthenticatedContext.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation